# Update Jquery progress bar, while reading txt file (from php)

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar

I have a 100.000 rows txt file and I need to read it in order to insert most part of it into my DB.
I'd like to use this plugin, as I found it very easy to use:

http://www.bram.us/projects/js_bramus/jsprogressbarhandler/#download

My problem is: I read the txt file with PHP, but I don't understant how to update the progress bar! 
I was thinking something like this

```
echo '$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: '.($k++).' });';
```

where `$k` goes from 0 to 100, but, WHERE do I have to put it??

Comment: I would do it like this. On page load, i run 2 ajax calls. First ajax request will be executed only once and actually start up your php-reading logic. Second ajax request will actually grab the current progress. You will need to modify your PHP-reading script, so it updates some current progress in session ($_SESSION['current_progress']). Then, in another php-script you will only get this var from session and echo the output. So, i put second ajax call on timer, like every second. By doing this i will send requests and get real-time progress, so i can manually update progress bar on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't possibly mix the php and the javascript:

1. The PHP will run and generate an HTML/JS file
2. The HTML/JS file will be sent to the client
3. The client will run the JS: `$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: XX });`

So `k` will be static.

--

If you really want to do something like that easily, you could use an intermediary DB table with three columns: txt_file, position, length
And often update this table while the PHP script is running over a txt file.

Client side, in Javascript, you can make an ajax request using jQuery for example every 5 or 10seconds, which is going to call an other PHP page, and this PHP page will only return the corresponding row from the intermediary table. Once you have the result you can update the progressbar.

--

It's the simplest solution to implement for you, but it's still really dirty, and the parsing of the txt file better have to be really long !

Comment: Thanks!! I thought it was not possibile, but I was just hoping.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this method:

http://spidgorny.blogspot.it/2012/02/progress-bar-for-lengthy-php-process.html

I think that this could help with some editing to the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to achieve this thing. PHP script executes first and then the output is sent to the client viewing the web page that is why you cannot show live status of your PHP script's processing to the client.

You will have to use a combination of AJAX and Database :

Create a table to track the progress of the loading of the text file. Whenever a user (client) sends a request to the page, keep on updating the table with the progress. Use Session id as the index on the table so that it would be easy to track the progress per client. Now use AJAX requests to get the progress from the table and present it to the client with your progress bar.